# How to bypass hard-coded shared library file requirement?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I'm coding in a Linux server with no root permission, so using package manager to install package to root directory like `yum install zsh` is not available. Therefore I download package to my user directory and update `PATH` to make it work.

Now I encounter a problem. I installed `zsh` and ran it, but it said

```
zsh: failed to load module `zsh/zle`: /usr/lib64/zsh/5.0.2/zsh/zle.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This `zle.so` file is now under `~/usr/lib64/zsh/5.0.2/zsh`, so I believe it is because I downloaded `zsh` to my user directory `~/usr/lib64` instead of `/usr/lib64`, and `zsh` hard-coded the shared library file it required, then error occurs.

I assume there exists some solutions like bypass this hard-coded requirement. If so, please feel free to tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, one way to bypass hardcoded requirements is to recompile it with proper configuration. Tr looking here https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/INSTALL if there's anything that helps you, especially `config.modules` parts.

Comment: @Destroy666 This helps me a lot! I was looking for something like this before. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44990/what-is-the-difference-between-path-and-ld-library-path